# Geopy: retrieving country names in English

Tags: python, geocode, country-codes, geopy

I am trying to reverse geocode coordinates and retrieve corresponding country codes using geopy. However, Geopy does not seem to provide a method for fetching country codes. So, I am trying to retrieve country names first, and then convert them to codes. Unfortunately, my code gives me country names in non-English languages.

**How can I fetch country names in English ?**

My code:

```
geolocator = Nominatim()
....
with open('coordinates.txt' , 'r') as readfile:
for line in readfile:
    fields = line.split("\t")
    address, (latitude, longitude) = geolocator.reverse(fields[1]+","+fields[2])
    if address:
        address = address.split(",")
        print "%s" % (address[-1])
```

The output I am getting:

```
Ελλάδα
Україна
Türkiye
Shqipëria
Tanzania
ኢትዮጵያ Ethiopia
Bosna i Hercegovina
Türkiye
Shqipëria
România
السودان - Sudan
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass in the language parameter to the `reverse()` request, e.g.:

```
geolocator.reverse(','.join(fields[1:3]), language='en')
```